# Activated Route problem Angular Data goes in a second

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

Im trying to fix this from long i wanna install routes so i added all routes app.route.ts i want to get the id parameter from the route . the data dissappears as soon as site is opened. Data is visible for less than a second then white screen is there

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../../services/product.service';
import { Product } from '../../common/product';
import { CommonModule, CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,CurrencyPipe],
  templateUrl: './product-list-grid.component.html',
  styleUrl: './product-list.component.css'
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  products:Product[]=[];
  currentCategoryId:number=1 ;
  constructor(private productService:ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const hasCategoryId:boolean=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.has('id');
    if(hasCategoryId){
      this.currentCategoryId=+this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    }
    this.productService.getProductlist(this.currentCategoryId).subscribe(
      data=>{
        this.products=data;
      }
    );
  }
 

}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from '../common/product';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/api/products";
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }
  getProductlist(theCategoryId:number):Observable<Product[]>{
     const searchUrl=`${this.baseUrl}/search/findByCategoryId?id=${theCategoryId}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(searchUrl).pipe(
      map(response=>response._embedded.products )
    )
  }
}
//    ${this.baseUrl}/search/findByCategoryId?id=${theCategoryId}

interface GetResponse{
  _embedded: {
    products: Product[];
  },
  page: {
    size: number;
    totalElements: number;
    totalPages: number;
    number: number;
  }
}
```

Im beginner tried using internet Could not find any such problem

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <!-- MENU SIDEBAR-->
  <aside class="menu-sidebar d-none d-lg-block">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="luv2shop" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-sidebar-content js-scrollbar1">
      <nav class="navbar-sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled navbar-list">
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/category/1" routerLinkActive="active-link"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Books</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/category/2" routerLinkActive="active-link"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Coffee Mugs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- END MENU SIDEBAR-->

  <div class="page-container">
    <!-- HEADER DESKTOP-->
    <header class="header-desktop">
      <div class="section-content section-content-p30">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="header-wrap">
            <form class="form-header" onsubmit="return false;" method="GET">
              <input class="au-input au-input-xl" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for data ..." />
              <button class="au-btn-submit" type="submit">
                Search
              </button>
            </form>
            <div class="cart-area d-n">
              <a href="shopping-detail.html">
                <div class="total">19.22 <span> 2</span> </div> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="account-wrap"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- END HEADER DESKTOP-->

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- ENDS PAGE CONTAINER -->

<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

in my html file     
is creating issue if i just call the component it is working correctly but this is not working
app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, withComponentInputBinding } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [ provideClientHydration(),provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideRouter(routes)]
};
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes,ActivatedRoute, provideRouter, withComponentInputBinding } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductListComponent } from './components/product-list/product-list.component';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'category',component:ProductListComponent},
    {path:'products',component:ProductListComponent},
    {path:'',redirectTo:'/products',pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'**',redirectTo:'/products',pathMatch:'full'}
];
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLinkActive, RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductListComponent } from './components/product-list/product-list.component';
import { HttpClientModule, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ProductListComponent,HttpClientModule,RouterOutlet,RouterLinkActive,RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-ecommerce';
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine you need to share the html and if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated, if replicated, please update the question with the full details!